# Apache Directory Studio doesn't show new created in WSO2 IS users

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are working with WSO2 IS v.5.3.0, but now we are going to upgrade this server.
Now I am trying to work with version 5.6 and 5.7. I installed clean, without any changes, with embedded LDAP and H2 DB version of server and I have problem:
When I add  new user through Management Console, Apache Directory Studio doesn't show this user and throws a exception :
`Error while reading entry
javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.CursorStudioNamingEnumeration.next(CursorStudioNamingEnumeration.java:317)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.CursorStudioNamingEnumeration.next(CursorStudioNamingEnumeration.java:1)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.SearchRunnable.searchAndUpdateModel(SearchRunnable.java:323)
.....`

It seems that WSO2 IS Management Console works properly. In WSO2 IS v.5.3.0 server all is OK

If I disable SCIM in UserStoreManager (false), Apache Directory studio works without any exceptions and all users in tree are displayed. Of course, they don't have SCIM attributes

If I create users through SCIM 1.1 or SCIM 2.0 intrerface data of these users isn't displayed in Apache Directory Studio and a exception is thrown.

What do I have to configure in Apache DS or in WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a claim mapping:
http://wso2.org/claims/resourceType to LDAP attribute *ref*. WSO2 IS sets this attribute to value *User*, but attribute *ref* has Syntax Description *IA5String* and  value *User* isn't correct. So, This claim mapping should be changed and then ApacheDS works properly.

Specifically: change the mapping from "ref" to "resourceType".  Also I found I had to delete any existing users I created from/in the WSO2 IS admin console and recreate them to get the Apache Directory Studio to read them.